# Printing arrays as tables

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have a multidimensional array where each key holds another array as value. I printed each key value pairs in separate tables. But I get unwanted space between tables (spacing between any two tables are not the same). How can I eliminate spacing as a whole?

```
foreach ($stockist as $key => $value) 
        {
        echo "<table align='center' border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td align = 'center'> <font color = 'blue'> $key</td></tr>";
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
              {
              echo "<tr><td align ='center'>$value1</td></tr><br>";
              }
        echo "</table>";    
        }
```

Comment: FYI: Don't use the `align` property. Don't use `<table>`'s for anything except tabular data. Don't use `<font>` tags at all. You should be able to substitute most of this with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get it all into a single table.

PHP

```
echo '<table>';
foreach ($stockist as $key => $value) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td></tr>';
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value1.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</table>;
```